# String format argument for traits.Any

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, nipype

I'm using enthought canopy's traits to wrap a code for Nipype. I know format argument is `%d` for integer variables. However, `Multiplication` variable below should be also a file.

```
multiplication = traits.Int(argstr='-mul %d', desc='multiplication', position=2)
```

So, I want to use `Any` instead of `Int` but I don't know what the corresponding format argument is for `Any`. How can I replace `%?` below?

```
multiplication = traits.Any(argstr='-mul %?', desc='multiplication', position=2)
```

Comment: I've got the answer `multiplication = traits.Any(argstr='-mul %s', desc='multiplication', position=2)`  It works for both integer and file

Comment: You should make your comment an answer, and accept it.  (There's nothing wrong with answering your own questions on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer `multiplication = traits.Any(argstr='-mul %s', desc='multiplication', position=2)` It works for both integer and file